# Not able to access .mm file into swift4

Tags: ios, swift4, objective-c++, bridging-header

I am working on a project which contains Objective C, Objective C++, and Swift4 classes. I am trying to access the .mm file (i.e Objective C++ file) into swift class but it's giving me an error and showing it's undeclared. I have added a bridging header to the project and imported Objective C++  file's header there.

Example to understand the problem:

I have A.mm class which has B.mm class imported in it. after adding A class into the bridging header compiler is giving an error in B class.

Error In B.h :

[image]

Please help

Comment: check in Target>Build Phase>Compile Source your `.mm` is listed or not, if not than add. it will work

Comment: Its added in compile sources.

Comment: What is the error in B class? can you please add some screenshot?

Comment: @aBilal17 Added, Please check

Comment: add 'typedef' before struct keyword and then check.

Comment: it's not working after adding a typedef to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift can only bridge to C and Objective-C. If your missing class uses C++ types in its header, Swift will be unable to read that file and just skip that class.

Can you change your Objective-C++ class so it only uses C++ types in its .mm file, and not in its .h file? Then it will look like a regular Objective-C class to Swift and you should be able to use it.

Alternately, you may be able to create a second class that is ObjC „on the outside“ and calls the ObjC++ class in its .mm, and that just hands through all the calls, translating C++ data types into simple C types or ObjC objects.

Look into „class extensions“ for declaring C++ properties and instance variables that would usually go into your header in the .mm file instead.

Comment: I tried the first approach of moving all CPP code into .mm file. It worked, all the error gone but how do I declare variables within the .h file of the type which I have moved into .mm file.

Comment: If the type is a C++ type, you can't. As soon as you put them in the header, Swift will be unable to read the file. So what you have to do is find equivalent ObjC or C types and use those instead, or convert to them (e.g. you can create an NSDictionary containing the values for a C++ class, then make the methods take a dictionary, and have the methods internally create the C++ class, fill it out with values from the dictionary, and do the reverse when the C++ code fills out a struct.

Comment: If you just mean you had instance variables in the header that are only used by your implementation file and don't need to be directly accessible from Swift, that is what class extensions are for (`@interface MyClass () { MyCppObject _foo; } @end`), you can put such a class extension into the .mm file, at the top, and then that code can behave just like it would if they were declared in the header.

Comment: Thanks for the response I tried the way of converting them into equivalent Objective C. I am marking your answer correct. Thanks for the help